# Java Sort by Distance

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a 2-dimensional array like this:

```
{1,3,5,6,2,2}

{6,2,4,7,2,1}

{17,28,32,1,35,45}

...
```

I have a function that can calculate the euclidean distance between any two arrays.  Assuming that the distance function operates correctly, what's the best way to sort the 2-dimensional array so that the arrays within the 2-dimensional array are swapped such that the one's closest to each other(distance wise) would be close to each other in the 2-dimensional array?

**Edit**

Is this boiling down to the travelling salesman problem again?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Euclidean distance is something you take between points. Are your arrays representing six-dimensional points?

Comment: woah.... this is just too complex for me

Comment: yeah... sounds like TSP to me. Depends though what you want to minimize...

Comment: "the one's closest to each other(distance wise) would be close to each other in the 2-dimensional array" is still ambiguous to me. Do you want each array to be bookended by the two arrays to which it is closest? What would the 2D answer be with points (1,1), (10,1), (20,1), (22, 2) and (22, 3)?

Comment: How would you compare the quality of a sorted array? Would you take the largest distance of two adjacent points, or the sum of all adjacent distances? Your problem is very similar to the travelling salesman problem. If you rank sorted arrays by the sum of their distances and include the distance from the last to the first, then you get the TSP itself.

Comment: TSP, appears everywhere I look, argh!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: I didn't fully solve it yet.  I'm still thinking there must be a way to get this information, something like a regression line through points in 6D space.  Haven't fully thought about how to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `TreeSet` and a comparator.

```
public class EuclidComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {

        return euclid_distance(o1, o2);

    }

}
```

Sort with:

```
    TreeSet<int[]> sort = new TreeSet<int[]>(new EuclidComparator());
    sort.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrays));
```

Or even easier:

```
    Arrays.sort(arrays, new EuclidComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by calculating all distances between the arrays and storing them in a TreeMap then create a map that is the reverse of this map and proceed with the sorted values to sort the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As I think about the problem, I believe that you need to calculate the distance from every point to every other point to know which is closest to which. So you have to effectively have a NxN grid for N points, no?

Then once you have the distance from Nsubn to ever other Nsubn, you need a ranking method to reduce the resulting matrix a-la linear algebra, no?

I presume it reduces to a matrix like this:

```
A {1,1,1}

B {3,3,3}

C {5,5,5}
```

And since the distance between each of those is desired to be the square root of 12, then you would have a matrix like thus:

```
         A         B         C
A        0  sqrt(12)  sqrt(48)
B sqrt(12)         0  sqrt(12)
C sqrt(48)  sqrt(12)         0
```

Since this is upper and lower diagonal, you can eliminate half of the grid and solve the other half... At this point it should be a solvable problem, no?

For reference, here's a different sample:

see also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+between+(5,1,3)+and+(3,5,1)

```
A {1,3,5}

B {5,1,3}

C {3,5,1}
```

Then you would have a matrix like thus:

```
         A         B         C
A        0  sqrt(24)  sqrt(24)
B sqrt(24)         0  sqrt(24)
C sqrt(24)  sqrt(24)         0
```

and this tells us all the points are equidistant from one another.

### Or did I go way off into left field on this one? What did I miss?

Comment: Where does the square root of 24 come into play?

Comment: @lagerbaer ~ my not being able to add? 3*2^2=12 eh?

Answer (score 0):

You must see that there is no "perfect" solution, where perfect would mean that "If entries A and B are adjacent in my array, then no point is closer to A than B is, and no point is closer to B than A is".

This is simply not possible.

Comment: Why not? It's a mathematically definable [binary|trinary] option. See my example. {1,1,1} is closer to {3,3,3} than to {5,5,5}. While it's true that {3,3,3} is equally close to the other two, for any hree given points A, B and C, I can define any two points as being "closest together"

Comment: If you choose one reference point, yes, you can sort other points with respect to their distance to the reference. But that's not the question. The idea of a perfect solution is that if A and B are k steps apart in the array, then B is the k-th nearest point to A. And you cannot have that globally. Try finding such an ordering for points in two dimensions that are arranged on a circle and you'll see that it's impossible.

Comment: @lagerbaer you MUST define a starting point or you can never uniquely identify a graph without considering all the points in the graph. And as you point out a cycle is a cycle is a cycle. How do you store the cycle in a database? You pick a point and unroll it. Or you store each node individually almost as a KVP. At least, that's my best first guess, for now. I've never designed a schema for storing graphs, but I think you see my point. If you're going to store it as a single object, then you'll need to unroll the cycle. It's how we process them mentally, no?

Comment: Either that or it's too late and I shouldn't be answering questions on SO or commenting, but instead should be studying my pillow

Comment: Storing the graph is not the issue. It's just that the author asked for a way to sort the nodes linearly in an array so that nearby elements in the array correspond to nearby points in 6D space. And I simply state that this isn't possible in a "perfect" fashion. I might think of an approximate solution / heuristic later.

Comment: Ah, then I agree. I was only looking for the approximate solution. I assume that any graph will be devolved into an explicit path, not a potential cycle or anything similar. Considering these are points in space, I presume he's looking to draw paths over points in the first place, or determine how paths may be most compactly desgined. I also wonder if such a solution to his problem already exists and the chaps on math.SE might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "post-sort" data structure you're looking for is a *map* of each point to its two nearest neighbors, not a two-dimensional array?  Unless I'm missing some property of your problem domain which makes this possible, you can't apply a [linear order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) to the points in your problem space.

Answer (score -1):

Write a quicksort, and use your distance function when you have to compare two elements. Wikipedia's got the algorithm for you.

Comment: This won't work. That way, in each step you just sort according to "proximity to pivot", but two nodes that are both close to a third node need not be close to each other themselves, and especially the upper half of your array (in each step) will contain nodes that are "far from the pivot", which does not tell us anything at all about how close these nodes themselves are.